# Looking for an embedded database for medium trust

Tags: asp.net, nosql, embedded-database, medium-trust

Is there some ( possibly OS ) embeddable DB engine file based ( like firebird or SQLite ) that can work on a Meidum Trust ASP.NET application ? Any no-sql solution for the same scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your hosting provider to install your favorite embedded DB into GAC, that may work.

SQL Server Compact should work under Medium Trust.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540.aspx